# ROS installation issue on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ros, catkin-install, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install these modules on a fresh ubuntu 14.04 OS

```
"python-rosdep", 
"python-rosdistro", 
"python-rosdistro-modules", 
"python-catkin-pkg", 
"python-catkin-pkg-modules", 
"python-netifaces", 
"python-qt4", 
"python-qt4-dev", 
"python-pyside", 
"libapr1", 
"libaprutil1", 
"libzzip-0-13"
```

and I am getting the following error

```
'/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef\" -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold\"    install 'python-rosdep' 'python-rosdistro' 'python-rosdistro-modules' 'python-catkin-pkg' 'python-catkin-pkg-modules' 'python-netifaces' 'python-qt4-dev' 'python-pyside' 'libapr1' 'libaprutil1' 'libzzip-0-13' -o APT::Install-Recommends=no' failed: dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.7-1_all.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up\ndpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.7-1_all.deb (--unpack):\n subprocess dpkg-deb
--control returned error exit status 2\ndpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg_0.4.7-100_all.deb' has premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up\ndpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg_0.4.7-100_all.deb (--unpack):\n subprocess dpkg-deb
--control returned error exit status 2\nErrors were encountered while processing:\n /var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.7-1_all.deb\n /var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg_0.4.7-100_all.deb\nE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)\n"
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299091/ros-installation-issue-on-ubuntu-14.04/) by [knights](https://answers.ros.org/users/36742/knights/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-07-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-31**:
Can you please update your question with the error again? Instead of using the `"` button though please use the `101010` because the `"` doesn't format terminal output (it's for quoting, not code/terminal output) and is very hard to read.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-31**:
Also, *how* are you attempting to install these packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're running into [ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg#227](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/issues/227) (duplicate with similar error message: [ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg#230](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/issues/230)).

From that issue: make sure to first update `dpkg` (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install dpkg`), as the original version of Ubuntu Trusty does not support LZMA archives in debian pkgs.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sibu](https://answers.ros.org/users/39241/sibu/) on 2018-12-30**:
Hi there,
Were you able to solve the issue of  " unmet dependencies "

**Comment by [sibu](https://answers.ros.org/users/39241/sibu/) on 2018-12-31**:
Can you please indicate the command here to install a specific module say "python-rosdistro" into ROS from a ubuntu terminal

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-31**:
Could I ask you to please not post multiple answers that aren't actually answers? Please use comments or post a new question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-31**:
As to your question: can you verify that you have an up-to-date `dpkg`? Because that is what is the issue that was resolved in this Q&A. Not the `python-rosdistro` version.

**Comment by [sibu](https://answers.ros.org/users/39241/sibu/) on 2018-12-31**:
Yes i have done the dpkg update

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-31**:
Then this Q&A is most likely not the place to ask for more information.

**Comment by [sibu](https://answers.ros.org/users/39241/sibu/) on 2018-12-31**:
Then where is the place ??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-31**:
Search for previous Q&As about `python-rosdistro` and if nothing fits then post a new one.